# Переключение в режим стандартного (desktop) вида

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, браузер, google-chrome-devtools

Есть инструменты разработчика

[image: switchdevicetype]

Как переключить вид инструментов разработчика к обычному виду (desktop)?

Comment: у вас 11 вопросов и ниразу вам не дали правильного ответа? Отмечайте как ответ правильный ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слева у вас иконка синим светится возле `elements` или `ctrl+shift+m`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]